# could not determine kind of name for C.free

Tags: go

I am trying to use `C.free` in my Golang application. My code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

// #include <stdlib.h>

import (
    "C"
)


//export FreeMemory
func FreeMemory(pointer *int64) {
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(pointer))
}
```

I have done some searching and I understand the error was because I don't have `stdlib.h` included, but I do.

This is my build command: `go build --buildmode=c-shared -o main.dll`. The error I get after building is: `could not determine kind of name for C.free`

My OS is Windows 10

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If the import of "C" is immediately preceded by a comment, that
> comment, called the preamble, is used as a header when compiling the C
> parts of the package. For example:
>
> ```
> // #include <stdio.h> 
> // #include <errno.h> 
> import "C"
> ```

Using immediately preceding Go line comments:

```
package main

import "unsafe"

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

//export FreeMemory
func FreeMemory(pointer *int64) {
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(pointer))
}

func main() {}
```

Using immediately preceding Go general comments:

```
package main

import "unsafe"

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

//export FreeMemory
func FreeMemory(pointer *int64) {
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(pointer))
}

func main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was that simple :)

Comment: ah, free is in stdlib.h